# How to disable close button in the ABORT Message box in nsis?

Tags: dialog, nsis

I have used nsi script for creating exe file.In the installation steps I have one message box which shows confirmation dialog box if user wants to cancel the installation.

```
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING "Are you sure want to abort the installation"
```

It produces following message box:

[image]

In this message box contains disable x close button in the above of the messagebox.now i want to remove that [x] close button.

[or]
Is there any other message box is available to do this job?

Comment: I doubt it would be possible without recompiling NSIS.

Comment: ok.thanks Charles.i edited the qn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS uses the normal [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and that only allows you control the buttons. Close means cancel/no/abort and this is normal windows behavior...

To change this you would need to implement a custom dialog and recompile NSIS.